# add new column to a reshaped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Right now I have an unstacked dataframe that came from something like:

```
                    Total_People  Age_Period   Total_income
Sge_group  History
 2015-01      1          12         2015-01      98730.77
 2015-02      1          24         2015-02      41476.93
              2          33         2015-02      84435.25
 2015-03      1          101        2015-03      40630.45
              2          99         2015-03      28969.07
              3          22         2015-03      83927.98
```

and when I unstack it as by

```
SGE = SGE['Total_income'].unstack(0)
```

it produces this table, which was expected:

```
sge_group   2015-01    2015-02    2013-03    
History
------------------------------------------
   1        98730.77   41476.93   40630.45
   2             nan   84435.25   28969.07
   3             nan        nan   32678.95
```

But I want to know if it is possible for me to add a column or two at the bottom where I can count the total number of people in each sge_group date or the total income of one, looking something like this like:

```
sge_group   2015-01    2015-02    2013-03    
History
------------------------------------------
   1        98730.77   41476.93   40630.45
   2             nan   84435.25   28969.07
   3             nan        nan   32678.95
Total_People      12         57        222
Total_Income       x          x          x
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) by first level of `MultiIndex` and aggregate by [`agg`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.agg.html) and `sum`, transpose and last [`append`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.append.html) to original `DataFrame`:

```
d = SGE['Total_income'].unstack(0)
print (d)
Sge_group   2015-01   2015-02   2015-03
History                                
1          98730.77  41476.93  40630.45
2               NaN  84435.25  28969.07
3               NaN       NaN  83927.98

df = SGE.groupby(level=0)['Total_People','Total_income'].sum().T
print (df)
Sge_group      2015-01    2015-02   2015-03
Total_People     12.00      57.00     222.0
Total_income  98730.77  125912.18  153527.5

SGE = d.append(df)
#alternative
#SGE = pd.concat([d, df])

print (SGE)
Sge_group      2015-01    2015-02    2015-03
1             98730.77   41476.93   40630.45
2                  NaN   84435.25   28969.07
3                  NaN        NaN   83927.98
Total_People     12.00      57.00     222.00
Total_income  98730.77  125912.18  153527.50
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for responding. Works perfect for calculating the income, but for counting the Total_people, it replaces it with the History. Any ideas how to get the sum total for all the people?

Comment: @KyleMcComb - Just realised I was a bit wrong, so answer was modified for aggregate sum for columns `Total_People` and `Total_income`